# many-to-many query into multiple columns for reporting

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, report

I have two tables with a linking table describing their many-to-many relationship.

```
TABLE buildings
    building_id
    building_name

TABLE facility_types
    facility_type_id
    facility_type

TABLE buildings_2_facility_types
    building_id
    facility_type_id
```

Now I need a report including the facility types as *columns* per each building.

```
REPORT:

  NAME        golf    pool    garage
Building A     Y        N        Y
Building B     N        Y        Y
Building C     N        N        N
```

How can I do this in SQL?

N.B.  This will be part of a much larger query involving lots of other tables.  I can do all that part, but converting rows to columns has got me vexed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting rows to columns is a real pain and you have to understand that SQL is really not meant for this kind of operation.

It's still possible, providing that the set of values to be transposed is **small**, **known** and **limited**. If not, you'll have to rely on you application layer.

An exemple on how to do it should help you understand the 3 conditions:

Assuming a table `buildings_2_facility_types`:

```
building_id facility_type_id
    1               1
    1               2
    2               3
    3               1
    3               3
```

You can get sthg out of it this way:

```
SELECT
    building_id,
    IF(SUM(facility_type_id = 1) > 0, "Y", "N") as facility_type_1,
    IF(SUM(facility_type_id = 2) > 0, "Y", "N") as facility_type_2,
    IF(SUM(facility_type_id = 3) > 0, "Y", "N") as facility_type_3
FROM buildings_2_facility_types
GROUP BY building_id;
```

See ? **small**, **known** and **limited** :/

Of course, you can also do it with a proc stock but it's usually not the prefered way.

Comment: what does `SUM` do in this case?

Comment: That's the nicest trick :) It gives you the number of occurences of the given value in the column. You can use it with any boolean condition. That's a pattern to understand as it has many performance-friendly usage.